# Add different layout between item in RecyclerView-AndroidX

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to add Different layout between item in my recyclerview, I have 3 item in first layout, and then I add second layout to item number 2, so It should have 4 item right now, (1-FirstLayout)-(2-SecondLayout)-(3FirstLayout)-(4FirstLayout), but I realize the position that I choose from my second layout replaced to the position first layout it becomes like this (1-FirstLayout)-(2-SecondLayout)-(3FirstLayout)
Iam not sure how to fix it

[image: It's GONE]

This is my Adapter

```
public class AdapterGameReview extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

public static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
public static final int TYPE_TOPREVIEWER = 2;
public static final int TYPE_ADSBANNER = 3;

private boolean mWithTopReviewer = true;
private boolean mWithAdsBanner = false;

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ModelGameReview> modelGameReviews;

private RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;

public AdapterGameReview(Context mContext, ArrayList<ModelGameReview> modelGameReviews, RecyclerViewClickListener mListener) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.modelGameReviews = modelGameReviews;
    this.mListener = mListener;
}

//Container
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    View v = null;

    if (viewType == TYPE_TOPREVIEWER) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_gamereviewtopreviewer, null);
        return new GameReviewTopReviewerViewHolder(v);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_ADSBANNER) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_adsbannerdummy, null);
        return new GameReviewAdsBannerViewHolder(v);
    } else {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_gamereview, null);
        return new GameReviewViewHolder(v, mListener);
    }

}

//Fill Container with Model Setter Getter
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if (holder instanceof AdapterGameReview.GameReviewTopReviewerViewHolder) {
        AdapterGameReview.GameReviewTopReviewerViewHolder gameReviewTopReviewerViewHolder = (AdapterGameReview.GameReviewTopReviewerViewHolder) holder;
        /*gameReviewTopReviewerViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });*/

    }else if (holder instanceof AdapterGameReview.GameReviewAdsBannerViewHolder) {
        AdapterFollowSavedGameReviewList.ShowmoreViewHolder showmoreViewHolder = (AdapterFollowSavedGameReviewList.ShowmoreViewHolder) holder;


    } else {

        final GameReviewViewHolder GameReviewViewHolder = (GameReviewViewHolder) holder;
        final ModelGameReview modelGameReviewX = modelGameReviews.get(position);

        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        requestOptions.error(R.drawable.bug);
        requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);
        requestOptions.centerCrop();

        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = inputFormat.parse(modelGameReviewX.getGamedate());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CharSequence niceDateStr = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(date.getTime(), Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
        //Set
        GameReviewViewHolder.TVGameDate.setText(niceDateStr);
        GameReviewViewHolder.TVGameTitle.setText(modelGameReviewX.getGametitle());
        GameReviewViewHolder.TVGameDescription.setText(modelGameReviewX.getGamedescription());
        Glide.with(mContext).load(modelGameReviewX.getGameimage())
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        GameReviewViewHolder.ProgressLoadPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        GameReviewViewHolder.ProgressLoadPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                .into(GameReviewViewHolder.IMGGameImage);

        GameReviewViewHolder.TVSeenCounter.setText(String.valueOf(modelGameReviewX.getSeencounter()));
        GameReviewViewHolder.TVCommentCounter.setText(String.valueOf(modelGameReviewX.getCommentcounter()));
        GameReviewViewHolder.TVLikeCounter.setText(String.valueOf(modelGameReviewX.getLikecounter()));

        if (modelGameReviewX.getIscomment() == 0) {
            GameReviewViewHolder.IMGCommentView.setImageResource(R.drawable.comment_off);
        } else if (modelGameReviewX.getIscomment() == 1) {
            GameReviewViewHolder.IMGCommentView.setImageResource(R.drawable.comment_on);
        }

        if (modelGameReviewX.getIslike() == 0) {
            GameReviewViewHolder.IMGLikeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_off);
        } else if (modelGameReviewX.getIslike() == 1) {
            GameReviewViewHolder.IMGLikeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_on);
        }

        if (modelGameReviewX.getIsbookmark() == 0) {
            GameReviewViewHolder.IMGBookmarkView.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_off);
            GameReviewViewHolder.IMGBookmarkView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (modelGameReviewX.getIsbookmark() == 1) {
            GameReviewViewHolder.IMGBookmarkView.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_on);
        }

        GameReviewViewHolder.TVReviewer.setText(modelGameReviewX.getReviewer());
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int itemCount = 0;
    if(mWithTopReviewer == true){
        itemCount++;
    }
        itemCount = modelGameReviews.size();

    return itemCount;
}

//TYPE_ITEM
public class GameReviewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView TVGameDate;
    TextView TVGameTitle;
    TextView TVGameDescription;
    ImageView IMGGameImage;

    TextView TVSeenCounter;
    TextView TVCommentCounter;
    TextView TVLikeCounter;

    ImageView IMGSeenView;
    ImageView IMGCommentView;
    ImageView IMGLikeView;

    TextView TVReviewer;

    ProgressBar ProgressLoadPhoto;

    ImageView IMGBookmarkView;
    private RelativeLayout ROWGameReviewContainer;

    private RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;

    public GameReviewViewHolder(View itemView, RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        TVGameDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_GameDate);
        TVGameTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_GameTitle);
        TVGameDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_GameDescription);
        IMGGameImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_GameImage);

        TVSeenCounter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_SeenCounter);
        TVCommentCounter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_CommentCounter);
        TVLikeCounter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_LikeCounter);

        IMGSeenView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_SeenView);
        IMGCommentView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_CommentView);
        IMGLikeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_LikeView);

        TVReviewer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_Reviewer);

        ProgressLoadPhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Progress_LoadPhoto);

        IMGBookmarkView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_BookmarkView);
        ROWGameReviewContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ROW_GameReviewContainer);

        mListener = listener;
        ROWGameReviewContainer.setOnClickListener(this);
        IMGCommentView.setOnClickListener(this);
        IMGLikeView.setOnClickListener(this);
        IMGBookmarkView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.ROW_GameReviewContainer:
                mListener.onRowGameReviewContainerClick(ROWGameReviewContainer, getAdapterPosition());
                break;
            case R.id.IMG_CommentView:
                mListener.onRowCommentViewClick(IMGCommentView, getAdapterPosition());
                break;
            case R.id.IMG_LikeView:
                mListener.onRowLikeViewClick(IMGLikeView, getAdapterPosition());
                break;
            case R.id.IMG_BookmarkView:
                mListener.onRowBookmarkViewClick(IMGBookmarkView, getAdapterPosition());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}

public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
    void onRowGameReviewContainerClick(View view, int position);
    void onRowCommentViewClick(View view, int position);
    void onRowLikeViewClick(View view, int position);
    void onRowBookmarkViewClick(View view, int position);
}

//TYPE_TOPREVIEWER
public class GameReviewTopReviewerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    Button BTNToBeReviewer;


    public GameReviewTopReviewerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        BTNToBeReviewer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.BTN_ToBeReviewer);

    }


}

//TYPE_ADSBANNER
public class GameReviewAdsBannerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    public GameReviewAdsBannerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


    }


}



@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (mWithTopReviewer && isPositionTopReviewer(position))
        return TYPE_TOPREVIEWER;
    if (mWithAdsBanner && isPositionAdsBanner(position))
        return TYPE_ADSBANNER;

    return TYPE_ITEM;
}


public boolean isPositionTopReviewer(int position) {
    return position == 1 && mWithTopReviewer;
}
public boolean isPositionAdsBanner(int position) {
    return position == getItemCount() - 1 && mWithAdsBanner;
}
public void setWithTopReviewer(boolean value) {
    mWithTopReviewer = value;
}
public void setWithAdsBanner(boolean value) {
    mWithAdsBanner = value;
}
```

}

This is My Model

```
public class ModelGameReview implements Serializable {

private int contentpage;
private String idcontent;
private String gametitle;

private String gamedate;
private String gameimage;
private String gamedescription;

private int seencounter;
private int commentcounter;
private int likecounter;

private int iscomment;
private int islike;
private int isbookmark;

private String reviewer;

private String value;
private String message;


public ModelGameReview(int contentpage, String idcontent, String gametitle, String gamedate, String gameimage, String gamedescription, int seencounter, int commentcounter, int likecounter, int iscomment, int islike, int isbookmark, String reviewer, String value, String message) {
    this.contentpage = contentpage;
    this.idcontent = idcontent;
    this.gametitle = gametitle;
    this.gamedate = gamedate;
    this.gameimage = gameimage;
    this.gamedescription = gamedescription;
    this.seencounter = seencounter;
    this.commentcounter = commentcounter;
    this.likecounter = likecounter;
    this.iscomment = iscomment;
    this.islike = islike;
    this.isbookmark = isbookmark;
    this.reviewer = reviewer;
    this.value = value;
    this.message = message;
}

public int getContentpage() {
    return contentpage;
}

public void setContentpage(int contentpage) {
    this.contentpage = contentpage;
}

public String getIdcontent() {
    return idcontent;
}

public void setIdcontent(String idcontent) {
    this.idcontent = idcontent;
}

public String getGametitle() {
    return gametitle;
}

public void setGametitle(String gametitle) {
    this.gametitle = gametitle;
}

public String getGamedate() {
    return gamedate;
}

public void setGamedate(String gamedate) {
    this.gamedate = gamedate;
}

public String getGameimage() {
    return gameimage;
}

public void setGameimage(String gameimage) {
    this.gameimage = gameimage;
}

public String getGamedescription() {
    return gamedescription;
}

public void setGamedescription(String gamedescription) {
    this.gamedescription = gamedescription;
}

public int getSeencounter() {
    return seencounter;
}

public void setSeencounter(int seencounter) {
    this.seencounter = seencounter;
}

public int getCommentcounter() {
    return commentcounter;
}

public void setCommentcounter(int commentcounter) {
    this.commentcounter = commentcounter;
}

public int getLikecounter() {
    return likecounter;
}

public void setLikecounter(int likecounter) {
    this.likecounter = likecounter;
}

public int getIscomment() {
    return iscomment;
}

public void setIscomment(int iscomment) {
    this.iscomment = iscomment;
}

public int getIslike() {
    return islike;
}

public void setIslike(int islike) {
    this.islike = islike;
}

public int getIsbookmark() {
    return isbookmark;
}

public void setIsbookmark(int isbookmark) {
    this.isbookmark = isbookmark;
}

public String getReviewer() {
    return reviewer;
}

public void setReviewer(String reviewer) {
    this.reviewer = reviewer;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

}

Comment: use getItemViewType() method of recycler view for using multiple view types

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman please read my Adapter code I already implemet it getItemViewType()

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented this method wrong

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int itemCount = 0;
    if(mWithTopReviewer == true){
        itemCount++;
    }
        itemCount = modelGameReviews.size();

    return itemCount;
}
```

It should be something similar

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int itemCount = modelGameReviews.size();
    if(mWithTopReviewer == true){
        itemCount++;
    }

    return itemCount;
}
```

Comment: I try it and it become crash java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.indofun.android.indojoy.Adapters.Adapter_GameReview.AdapterGameReview.onBindViewHolder(AdapterGameReview.java:103)

Comment: @SunggakiChannel return value of `getItemCount()` indicates how many items you have inside your list.  you array size is three. but if you want to show four items, the array also should have 4 items.

Comment: so if(mWithTopReviewer == true){
        itemCount++;
    } should make the Size become 4 right?, but it still crash